# Get the file path from attachment on Gmail

Tags: android, android-intent

I´m trying to get a csv file from an email attachment , the idea is that when user selects the attachment an option to open with my app will appear . I need to know the best way to get the file path from the attachment .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not necessarily a "file path" for the attachment.

If you have an activity set up to view files of the proper MIME type, and the user chooses to use your activity to view the email attachment, you will get a `Uri` to that attachment in `getIntent().getData()`. That `Uri` *may* be a `file:///` `Uri`. It *may* be something else. In particular, for Gmail, it will be a `content://` `Uri`. Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the contents pointed to by that `content://` `Uri`.